# Is it possible to pass Javascript objects to ActiveX (and use them)?

Tags: javascript, c++, mfc, activex, npapi

I want to pass JavaScript objects (JSON and function objects) into my ActiveX control. Ideally, I could manipulate JavaScript objects (e.g. reading or modifying JSON) and perform JavaScript function calls from within the ActiveX control (using C++). Is any of this possible, or do I have to settle for passing strings?

For example, here is what I can do in Firefox. Notice that I have a reference to a JSON object, and I can also perform JavaScript function calls:

```
NPString jsonToString(NPP instance, NPObject* json)
{
    NPVariant result;
    NPVariant arg;
    NPIdentifier identifier;

    /* Get the global object */
    NPObject* windowObj = NULL;
    g_NPNFuncs.getvalue(instance, NPNVWindowNPObject, &windowObj);

    /* Get JSON object */
    identifier = g_NPNFuncs.getstringidentifier("JSON");
    g_NPNFuncs.getproperty(instance, windowObj, identifier, &result);
    NPObject* jsonObj = NPVARIANT_TO_OBJECT(result);

    /* Call stringify */
    identifier = g_NPNFuncs.getstringidentifier("stringify");
    OBJECT_TO_NPVARIANT(json, arg);
    g_NPNFuncs.invoke(instance, jsonObj, identifier, &arg, 1, &result);

    return NPVARIANT_TO_STRING(result);
}
```

**Edit** - Here's the solution I came up with:

IDL file:

```
[id(TEST_ID)] BSTR Test(BSTR data, IDispatch* function);
```

Dispatch map:

```
DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CApp, "test", TEST_ID, Test, VT_BSTR, VTS_BSTR VTS_DISPATCH)
```

Interface function:

```
BSTR Test(BSTR data, IDispatch* function)
```

Calling the JavaScript function object:

```
VARIANTARG args[1];
args[0].vt = VT_BSTR;
args[0].bstrVal = _bstr_t(dataStr).GetBSTR();

DISPPARAMS params;
params.cArgs = 1;
params.cNamedArgs = 0;
params.rgvarg = args;

HRESULT hresult = function->Invoke(0, IID_NULL,
    LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, &params, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Calling IDispatch::Invoke with a DISPID of 0 seems to work for invoking a function object. However, to call a method of an object, you have to get the corresponding DISPID first, as Taxilian said. GetNextDispID should work for that (first QueryInterface for IDispatchEx; casting to IDispatchEx seems to work too, but maybe isn't safe).

Comment: You should check out this question: [Passing array of bytes from ActiveX to javascript and vice versa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926723/passing-array-of-bytes-from-activex-to-javascript-and-vice-versa). As long as you 'stringify' your object, and pass it as a string (obv), you're golden.

Comment: Yeah I saw that question. Stringify is not necessarily the only thing I want to do; it's just an example. That said, I might end up just passing strings anyway if this proves to be too complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, I'm aparently not very bright today because I just wrote up an answer completely missing the part where you said the npapi plugin code was an example =]

so, to answer the correct question, yes you can.  The type in ActiveX that closest correlates to NPObject is [IDispatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (or [IDispatchEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sky96ah7%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)). Rather than having a GetProperty, SetProperty, and Invoke, you merely call Invoke and tell it if it should get a property, set a property, or invoke a method. You'll first have to query to get the DISPID of the member in question; similar to a NPIdentifier, DISPID is a mapping between a string and a number.

If you haven't seen it you should really look at [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org), which provides an abstraction to allow you to write a plugin that works on both NPAPI and ActiveX with the same codebase. It has a [wrapper to allow it to use IDispatch objects](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/ActiveXCore/IDispatchAPI.cpp) that you'll probably find useful as an example.

So long story short, you can use JS objects pretty much the same way you could with a NPObject by using IDispatch (or even better, IDispatchEx). Most things from javascript come through as a IDispatchEx, but occasionally I've seen instances where IDispatch failover support was needed.

Hope it helps, and I hope my initial response (before I re-read your question) didn't throw you off.

Comment: So I added an IDispatch* parameter to a function in my interface (defined in the IDL file). Then I casted it to an IDispatchEx (couldn't specify it in the IDL because it doesn't seem to like the DispEx.h header). That all seems to be OK. However, if I pass in a JavaScript function object, do you have any idea how to call it? GetNextDispID doesn't return any members. BTW, the FireBreath code has been helpful to look at - it's too bad I can't use it for the time being due to business concerns.

Comment: Nevermind, I found out that I can just Invoke with dispid of 0 from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681327/is-dispid-value-reliable-for-invokes-on-idispatchs-from-scripts